# Ubuntu 20.10 problem in installing python based app

Tags: software-installation, python

I have this problem in installing python based app (key and mouse,macro record app:[robotux](https://abatzill.de/cms/index.php/Robotux) ):

```
so@sosa:/media/so/915b062e-7148-4edb-8355-1d342f97edfd/so/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i robotux_0.4_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package robotux.
(Reading database ... 148292 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack robotux_0.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking robotux (0.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of robotux:
 robotux depends on python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~).
 robotux depends on python-xlib; however:
  Package python-xlib is not installed.
 robotux depends on gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1; however:
  Package gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package robotux (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 robotux
```

my OS version is:

```
so@sosa:/media/so/915b062e-7148-4edb-8355-1d342f97edfd/so/Downloads$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla (development branch)
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

Update:

also i have installed the `gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1` by synaptic and installed pyhton2 in Ubuntu 20 and `python-xlib` manually by downloading it and by `python setup.py install` command like this:

```
so@sosa:~/Downloads/pip-20.1.1$ pip install python-xlib
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: python-xlib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_xlib-0.27-py2.7.egg (0.27)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six-1.15.0-py2.7.egg (from python-xlib) (1.15.0)
so@sosa:~/Downloads/pip-20.1.1$
```

But i have again that problem, like this:

```
$ sudo apt -f install ./robotux_0.4_all.deb
[sudo] password for so: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Note, selecting 'robotux' instead of './robotux_0.4_all.deb'
robotux is already the newest version (0.4).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 robotux : Depends: python-xlib but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Or by **dpkg** :

```
$ sudo dpkg -i robotux_0.4_all.deb
(Reading database ... 150837 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack robotux_0.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking robotux (0.4) over (0.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of robotux:
 robotux depends on python-xlib; however:
  Package python-xlib is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package robotux (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 robotux
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Philip the OP is using groovy, which no longer has the `python-xlib` package.

Comment: I misread.  [Ubuntu 20.10 has not been released yet](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).  As such packaging problems like this are likely to be common. Especially if you are installing third party packages directly downloaded from their website.

Answer (score 0):

Install the python-xlib package from Ubuntu 20.04 in Ubuntu 20.10. python-xlib has two dependencies in the Ubuntu 20.10 default repositories which can be installed by apt. Open the terminal and type.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python2 python-six  
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-xlib/python-xlib_0.23-2build1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./python-xlib_0.23-2build1_all.deb
```

Change directories using `cd` to the directory containing robotux_0.4_all.deb and run the following command to install Robotux.

```
sudo apt install ./robotux_0.4_all.deb
```